# Unity plugin - can't rebind the launcher button

Tags: unity, compiz

I'm running 12.04 and I'd like to use my <kbd>Super</kbd> as the button to open the launcher, currently I'm using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to essentially open the first item in the launcher.

I have the Compiz tools installed, and I've tried editing the launcher button, but as soon as I set it, it changes back to 'Disabled'.

Does anyone have any idea how I can find out if the button is already bound, or force it in some way? I'd like to be able to use it to see the shortcut help window also.

It seems that this also stops all keyboard shortcuts using the <kbd>Super</kbd> key as seen here, http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/unity-gets-shortcut-hints-overlay-and.html

**Update one**
I've changed the Super key in my keyboard settings to be 'Meta' which seems to have made a difference, but I still can't rebind that launcher shortcut

**Update two**
Looks like this is a bug, https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1151786

Comment: I've changed the Super key in my keyboard settings to be 'Meta' which seems to have made a difference, but I still can't rebind that launcher shortcut.

Comment: Please provide additional information only by editing your question and not within a comment. Comments might/will eventually be deleted and so your information would get lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered by Dell. They have a package which specifically disabled the button.

Removing this package has solved this issue for me.

`sudo apt-get remove dell-super-key`

https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1154430